# Linking a .asp page from .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, asp-classic

I am wondering whether could I link a .asp page from a .aspx page. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and I have few .asp pages created before. I want to transfer my new .aspx page to some of these .asp pages. But when I do that it is not showing up in my web browser. It moves to that page but nothing is shown up. I am pretty new to ASP.NET and please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If should not happen if you are using IIS express to debug (start directly within Visual Studio), but if you are using IIS to host and run the site, it might be because you did not add the asp support to IIS, you could double check it by going to IIS manager -> Handler Mappings, looking for aspClassic, if it does not exist, it means you need to go into Program And Features in control panel to enable that.